# Why does changing the magic number of a multi-boot header break the kernel?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, low-level

I am following the *OSDev* tutorial on building a bare bones kernel at [https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). I also managed to compile the kernel and boot it using the *.bin* file generated upon compilation. The OS could not boot upon running. [OS boot error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG3kd.png) Here is the code I'm using in *GAS*.

```
/* Declare constants for the multiboot header. */
.set ALIGN,    1<<0             /* align loaded modules on page boundaries */
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1             /* provide memory map */
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  /* this is the Multiboot 'flag' field */
.set MAGIC,    0x59F49148       /* 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header */
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS) /* checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot */
 
/* 
Declare a multiboot header that marks the program as a kernel. These are magic
values that are documented in the multiboot standard. The bootloader will
search for this signature in the first 8 KiB of the kernel file, aligned at a
32-bit boundary. The signature is in its own section so the header can be
forced to be within the first 8 KiB of the kernel file.
*/
.section .multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM
 
/*
The multiboot standard does not define the value of the stack pointer register
(esp) and it is up to the kernel to provide a stack. This allocates room for a
small stack by creating a symbol at the bottom of it, then allocating 16384
bytes for it, and finally creating a symbol at the top. The stack grows
downwards on x86. The stack is in its own section so it can be marked nobits,
which means the kernel file is smaller because it does not contain an
uninitialized stack. The stack on x86 must be 16-byte aligned according to the
System V ABI standard and de-facto extensions. The compiler will assume the
stack is properly aligned and failure to align the stack will result in
undefined behavior.
*/
.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
.skip 16384 # 16 KiB
stack_top:
 
/*
The linker script specifies _start as the entry point to the kernel and the
bootloader will jump to this position once the kernel has been loaded. It
doesn't make sense to return from this function as the bootloader is gone.
*/
.section .text
.global _start
.type _start, @function
_start:
    /*
    The bootloader has loaded us into 32-bit protected mode on a x86
    machine. Interrupts are disabled. Paging is disabled. The processor
    state is as defined in the multiboot standard. The kernel has full
    control of the CPU. The kernel can only make use of hardware features
    and any code it provides as part of itself. There's no printf
    function, unless the kernel provides its own <stdio.h> header and a
    printf implementation. There are no security restrictions, no
    safeguards, no debugging mechanisms, only what the kernel provides
    itself. It has absolute and complete power over the
    machine.
    */
 
    /*
    To set up a stack, we set the esp register to point to the top of the
    stack (as it grows downwards on x86 systems). This is necessarily done
    in assembly as languages such as C cannot function without a stack.
    */
    mov $stack_top, %esp
 
    /*
    This is a good place to initialize crucial processor state before the
    high-level kernel is entered. It's best to minimize the early
    environment where crucial features are offline. Note that the
    processor is not fully initialized yet: Features such as floating
    point instructions and instruction set extensions are not initialized
    yet. The GDT should be loaded here. Paging should be enabled here.
    C++ features such as global constructors and exceptions will require
    runtime support to work as well.
    */
 
    /*
    Enter the high-level kernel. The ABI requires the stack is 16-byte
    aligned at the time of the call instruction (which afterwards pushes
    the return pointer of size 4 bytes). The stack was originally 16-byte
    aligned above and we've pushed a multiple of 16 bytes to the
    stack since (pushed 0 bytes so far), so the alignment has thus been
    preserved and the call is well defined.
    */
    call kernel_main
 
    /*
    If the system has nothing more to do, put the computer into an
    infinite loop. To do that:
    1) Disable interrupts with cli (clear interrupt enable in eflags).
       They are already disabled by the bootloader, so this is not needed.
       Mind that you might later enable interrupts and return from
       kernel_main (which is sort of nonsensical to do).
    2) Wait for the next interrupt to arrive with hlt (halt instruction).
       Since they are disabled, this will lock up the computer.
    3) Jump to the hlt instruction if it ever wakes up due to a
       non-maskable interrupt occurring or due to system management mode.
    */
    cli
1:  hlt
    jmp 1b
 
/*
Set the size of the _start symbol to the current location '.' minus its start.
This is useful when debugging or when you implement call tracing.
*/
.size _start, . - _start
```

I tried to change the *magic number* from *0x1BADB002* to *0x59F49148* and linked the kernel and header successfully. Upon booting from *Qemu*, the OS could not run. Could anyone explain why this occurs?

Comment: The comment says “'magic number' lets bootloader find the header.”  So without this number, the bootloader will not find the header.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @fuz But is the magic number something set by the bootloader or is it set by the definition in the multiboot header? Either way, can it be changed somehow?

Comment: It is set by the multiboot specification. No, you can't change it, unless you change the bootloader so it looks for a non-standard value. The whole point of multiboot is that you don't need to write your own bootloader. In exchange, you need to adhere to a certain format which includes the magic number.

Comment: @IsaacCiliaAttard The magic number is specified in the multiboot header specification, which is defined by GRUB, the boot loader.  You are free to change it, but then it is no longer a correct multiboot header and your kernel will not boot.  Once again, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @fuz I expected it to boot anyway. I thought that the magic number is set by the header and that different OSes are discriminated by their unique magic numbers. Forgive me for I am still a beginner at low-level programming.

Comment: The bootloader doesn't care what OS it is booting. The whole idea is that it works for any compliant OS. It is searching for the magic number to be sure it is booting a real kernel and that it can find and rely on the values of the other fields.

Comment: @IsaacCiliaAttard Ok.  That is indeed a reasonable theory.  The magic number does indeed discriminate: but between multiboot-capable kernels and those that can be booted by some other means.  The boot loader does not care which OS it is that you boot.

Comment: The multiboot magic number lets the bootloader recognize that it's actually a multiboot executable at all, not some other bytes that happen to be there.  Same if you try to run a binary under an OS, it checks a magic number to see if it's an ELF executable, and if so then looks at more numbers to see if it's for the right OS/CPU.  If not an ELF executable, then it checks for a `#!` script, etc.